# How to set a shortcut to change to specified language (Gnome 2)

Tags: shortcuts, gnome-classic, input-language

I am using 4 languages, and may need even more soon. That makes switching by repeatedly pressing Ctrl+Shift until I get to the language I need a little bit uncomfortable A while ago in windows I could easily set up Ctrl+Shift+Num to switch to a specific language. For example: Ctrl+Shift+1 to switch to English, Ctrl+Shift+2 to switch to Russian, Ctrl+Shift+3 to switch to Ukrainian, etc. How do I set stuff this way in Gnome 2 enviroment?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that. You may want to try switching input language via the input source indicator instead.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy to do by using the `setxkbmap` command and keyboard shortcuts:

- `setxkbmap us` for USA English
- `setxkbmpa ru` for Russian
- `setxkbmap uk` ...not sure is that's Ukranian

etc.

Just assign shortcuts to these commands, and they should work regardless of what DE you use.